# Regex to find special pattern in anchor tag

Tags: regex

i need to make a regex which can match anchor tags having href attribute. It should match any anchor tag having href attribute regardless of having any other attribute or not.
So far i came up with this

```
<\s*a\s*\w*\W*\w*\W*\s*href[^>]*>
```

but its not working on cases like
`<a name="anything" id="anything" href="anything"/>`

Comment: If this is but a one-use dirty script, you shouldn't parse (x)html with regex but rather with an html or xml parser.

Comment: Stop trying to parse html with regex. Use a html parser instead

Comment: In addition to others' comments - what if your tag is on multiple lines.

Comment: @lorenzog regex should work if it is on multiple lines

Comment: Always good to remember : [don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @AbdulAhadShahid don't guess. Try it.

Answer (score -2):

Try this one:

```
<a\s+[^>]*\bhref\b=\"[^\"]+\"[^>]*>
```

Comment: It's validating `<a newhref="nohref"/>` wich isn't a valid href attribute. Add a check for a whitespace before the `href`

Comment: And it doesn't validate this case : `<a href="anything"/>`

Comment: Don't realy know since it's not my question

Comment: Will not match `< a...`.

Comment: No it is not OK. Stop trying to come up with [a broken solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936144/regex-to-find-special-pattern-in-anchor-tag#comment55632138_33936144). There are (subtle) ways this will break. Just stop.